# Fastest way to insert a value in int List and then sort the list

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I am working with dynamic int generic List. I am trying to add and then sort the list in descending order. This operation occurs number of timmes. 
Currently I am using Linq to do this as.

```
list.Add(b);
list = list.OrderByDescending(i => i).ToList();
```

Is there some way to improve the performance of this operation overall.

Comment: You can use `SortedDictionary` or `SortedSet`

Comment: Or a SortedList... a SortedSet would only help if you don't have duplicate values.

Comment: @ZoharPeled `SortedList` does not allow duplicates either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current approach is *suboptimal* as each time you add an element you're sorting the entire list again which can be avoided and you're constructing a new list each time you add an integer to the `List<int>` which again can be avoided.

As you already have a `List<int>` I'd use the methods that belong to this class as opposed to using LINQ to avoid the overhead.

What I suggest is to create an extension method as such:

```
public static class Extensions {
        public static void InsertElementDescending(this List<int> source, 
                int element)
        {
            int index = source.FindLastIndex(e => e > element);
            if (index == 0 || index == -1)
            {
                source.Insert(0, element);
                return;
            }
            source.Insert(index + 1, element);
        }
}
```

Then the use case would be:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();

list.InsertElementDescending(1);
list.InsertElementDescending(2);
list.InsertElementDescending(233);
list.InsertElementDescending(0);
list.InsertElementDescending(-2);
```

The list will now have the elements in descending order.

Overall this has better performance than your current approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach indeed has a lot of overhead, because a new `List<T>` is created on each insertion.

You can speed this up by sorting in place. Consider that after adding the item at the back of the original pre-sorted list all you need to do is to move that item back until you hit an item that is greater than the newly inserted one. You can do it like this:

```
static void InsertSorted<T>(IList<T> list, T item) where T : IComparable<T> {
    list.Add(item);
    var i = list.Count-1;
    for ( ; i > 0 && list[i-1].CompareTo(item) < 0 ; i--) {
        list[i] = list[i-1];
    }
    list[i] = item;
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/Pr0PKO)